# Append query error

Tags: sql, database, ms-access, insert

My primary key of Specialization table is complex and consists of two columns: Specialization_id and Specialty_id(which is foreign key of Specialty table).
I am going to make insert query by creating a new SPECIALIZATION of an existing specialty.
I have some specializations in my table already, primary key for one specialty with id = 1 looks like   (1,1) (2,1), with id = 2 looks like (1,2) (2,2).
Now I am going to add a new Specialization to Specialization table, but this Specialization should reference to existing Specialty.
My idea is

```
    INSERT INTO Specialization ( Specialization_name, Specialization_id, Specialty_id )
VALUES( 'Network technologies','(SELECT Max(Specialization_id) FROM Specialization WHERE Specialty_id = '2')+1', '2');
```

I've tried with '' clauses and without it, still, I am getting errors.
What should I do here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your main error is the quotes, since your subquery is quoted it will get processed as a string and not a query.

Also, you don't need to use a subquery if you don't have a main query:

```
INSERT INTO Specialization ( Specialization_name, Specialization_id, Specialty_id )
SELECT 'Network technologies' As a, Max(Specialization_id)+1 As b, 2 As c
FROM Specialization WHERE Specialty_id = 2
```

However, like dstudeba said, relying on autonumbers for creating new IDs is probably smarter.

Comment: This code gives an error to me : Data type mismatch in criteria expression.
I have Specialization_name as short text, Specialization_id as number and Specialty_id as number.
And overall I don't get this query, where is VALUES(..)?
And also my query isn't working without quotes also, gives the following error: query input must contain at least one table or query.

Comment: There is no `VALUES`, it's an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` clause, documented [here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INSERT-INTO-Statement-e12fd58b-33b1-479c-8221-e9f245ab8d24). If there's a type mismatch, please provide the data types for each fields. If `Specialization_id` is not numeric, `Max` is going to return unexpected results (edited to assume specialty_id is numeric)

Comment: I have Specialization_name as short text, Specialization_id as number and Specialty_id as number.

Comment: Ah, then the current edit shouldn't cause any mismatches. I've also removed MySQL from your question, since those types and this SQL is Access SQL, not MySQL

Answer (score 2):

In a database like MySQL or ORACLE you should not programatically increment the primary key.  Instead you should set the field to `AUTOINCREMENT` when you design the database.

That would change your `INSERT` statement to:

```
 INSERT INTO Specialization (Specialization_name, Specialty_id)
 VALUES('Network technologies', '2')
```

which is not only much easier, it is safer.

edited to add: Are you sure `Specialty_id` is a string?  I would think it would be some kind of number.

Comment: I am not an expert, but I won't work correct with complex primary key. I made it because I read somewhere that when we have a composition we have to have a complex PK.

Comment: @RaiseLtwiCe are you referring to a composite primary key?  If so you are correct, you don't autoincrement a composite primary key, but you don't manually increment it either.  What are you trying to do with your primary key that you need to manually assign it?

Comment: Sorry for typo, yes, my primary key is composite. I will try to explain situation in general. I have a table Specialization and Specialty. A record in Specialization table which refers to some specialty cannot exist without the required specialty in Specialty table. So, according to my knowledge, my PK of Specialization table would be (Specialization_id, Specialty_id(as FK of Specialty table)). If I will increment specialization_id I will lose some ids, for example I have PK (1,1) (2,1) and when I will have to refer to another specialty_id it will be (3,2) (4,2) instead of (1,2) (2,2).

Comment: Actually, when I was writing this comment I've got a question. Does it really matter that I will lose this (1,2) (2,2) as PK?

Comment: @RaiseLtwiCe I really think you should go talk to the database designer and get recommendations from them as this is not how I would design my database.  If you are designing the database yourself you should really have a good reason for using a composite primary key.  If the only reason is to make sure there is an existing `Specialty` for every `Specialization` there are easier and more standard ways to do it.  The standard way to do it would be to make `Specialty_id` a foreign key in the `Specialization` table, and make `Specialization_id` the primary key in the `Socialization` table.

Comment: I think in this case I am able to create a record of a specialization which doesn't refers to any of specialties. That's should not happen in my DB(I am trying to make a reflection of real life University structure). Am I right?

Comment: @RaiseLtwiCe If you make sure the foreign key isn't nullable you shouldn't have that problem.  The way you have set it up the checks are in the Application layer anyway so it really isn't that different.  You are just making things more difficult than you need to.